# XSLT multiple document output for combined subelements

Tags: xml, xslt, split, message, composition

I have a command contained with a message and body that need to be duplicated. Like so:

```
<message>
 <body>
  <command name="1"/>
  <command name="2"/>
 </body>
</message>
```

What I would like is:

```
 <message>
 <body>
  <command name="1"/>
 </body>
</message>

<message>
 <body>
   <command name="2"/>
 </body>
</message>
```

I'm using the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="/message/body/*"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$items">
        <xsl:result-document href="section{position()}.xml">
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../.[position()]"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

A few clarifications: the name attribute is not a position attribute so it can vary. The command name is not known and can vary. Commands are nodes themselves and can contain elements.

Based on Dabbler's code I was able to produce this which successfully parses the following:

```
<message>
<body>
 <commandA num="1"/>
 <commandB num="5"/>
 <commandC num="25">
    <subCommandT />
 </commandC>
</body>
</message>
```

into

```
<message>
 <body>
  <commandA num="1"/>
 </body> 
</message>

<message>
 <body>
  <commandB num="5"/>
 </body>
</message>

<message>
<body>
<commandC num="25">
      <subCommandT />
 </commandC>
</body>
</message>
```

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/message/body/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*">
            <xsl:with-param name="CmdId" select="generate-id(.)" tunnel="yes"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="CmdPosition" select="position()" tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:param name="CmdId" as="xs:string" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="CmdPosition" as="xs:integer" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:result-document href="section{$CmdPosition}.xml">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="body/*">
    <xsl:param name="CmdId" as="xs:string" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = $CmdId">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you Dabbler!

Here is a sample of the original command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tst:Message xmlns:tst="http://www.someschema.com/v1.4" xmlns:pc="http://www.someotherschema.com/v1.5">
<tst:Body tst:hostId="1" tst:machineId="77.D2" tst:dateTimeSent="2012-07-11T15:30:46">
    <tst:commandOption tst:deviceId="1" tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:46" tst:commandId="1" tst:sessionType="response" tst:sessionId="28" >
        <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="12" tst:configurationId="3148"/>
    </tst:commandOption>
    <tst:commandOption tst:deviceId="1" tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:48" tst:commandId="2" tst:sessionType="response" tst:sessionId="29" >
        <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="13" tst:configurationId="3149"/>
    </tst:commandOption>
    <tst:commandOption tst:deviceId="1" tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:50" tst:commandId="3" tst:sessionType="response" tst:sessionId="30" >
        <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="14" />
    </tst:commandOption>
    <pc:pContext pc:deviceId="1" pc:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:24:17" pc:commandId="4" pc:sessionId="47146">
        <pc:Exit pc:transactionId="3116380"/>
    </pc:pContext>
</tst:Body>
```

Comment: Bill, You may be interested in a much simpler and shorter solution.

Comment: Dimitre - I'm all ears. I need this to work on XSL 1.0 since I eventually have to do this in Java.

Comment: Bill, Just have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but this works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="/message/body/*">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/*">
            <xsl:with-param name="CmdNum" select="position()" tunnel="yes"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="message">
      <xsl:param name="CmdNum" as="xs:integer" tunnel="yes"/>

      <xsl:result-document href="section{$CmdNum}.xml">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:result-document>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="command">
      <xsl:param name="CmdNum" as="xs:integer" tunnel="yes"/>

      <xsl:if test="@name = $CmdNum">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem with the code as you have it is that the filter is applied to the `message` element instead of the `command`element.

Comment: I forgot to add that I don't know the name of the command elements. From your code I was able to produce the correct result after modifying it a bit. Answer is below.

Comment: In that case, all you need to do is have the template match `body/*`instead of `command` (provided there are no other child elements in `body` that interfere).

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I did. I can't answer my own question so I edited the original. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**As simple as this (a single template and only a few lines of code):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDest" select="'file:///c:/temp/delete/'"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'command')]">
    <xsl:result-document href="{$pDest}section{position()}.xml">
        <message>
            <body>
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </body>
        </message>
    </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<message>
    <body>
        <commandA num="1"/>
        <commandB num="5"/>
        <commandC num="25">
            <subCommandT />
        </commandC>
    </body>
</message>
```

**three XML files are created**:

C:\temp\delete\section1.xml:

```
<message>
   <body>
      <commandA num="1"/>
   </body>
</message>
```

C:\temp\delete\section2.xml:

```
<message>
   <body>
      <commandB num="5"/>
   </body>
</message>
```

C:\temp\delete\section3.xml

```
<message>
   <body>
      <commandC num="25">
         <subCommandT/>
      </commandC>
   </body>
</message>
```

---

**Update**:

The OP has now provided his "real" source XML document:

```
<tst:Message xmlns:tst="http://www.someschema.com/v1.4"
 xmlns:pc="http://www.someotherschema.com/v1.5">
<tst:Body tst:hostId="1" tst:machineId="77.D2"
          tst:dateTimeSent="2012-07-11T15:30:46">
    <tst:commandOption tst:deviceId="1"
                       tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:46"
                       tst:commandId="1"
                       tst:sessionType="response"
                       tst:sessionId="28" >
        <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="12"
                              tst:configurationId="3148"/>
    </tst:commandOption>
    <tst:commandOption tst:deviceId="1"
                       tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:48"
                       tst:commandId="2"
                       tst:sessionType="response"
                       tst:sessionId="29" >
        <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="13"
                              tst:configurationId="3149"/>
    </tst:commandOption>
    <tst:commandOption tst:deviceId="1"
                       tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:50"
                       tst:commandId="3"
                       tst:sessionType="response"
                       tst:sessionId="30" >
        <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="14" />
    </tst:commandOption>
    <pc:pContext pc:deviceId="1" pc:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:24:17"
                pc:commandId="4" pc:sessionId="47146">
        <pc:Exit pc:transactionId="3116380"/>
    </pc:pContext>
</tst:Body>
</tst:Message>
```

**We use essentially the same transformation as above, changing only the strings that are used for the start of names**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDest" select="'file:///c:/temp/delete/'"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'tst:commandOption')]">
    <xsl:result-document href="{$pDest}section{position()}.xml">
        <message>
            <body>
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </body>
        </message>
    </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**And the result is the creation of these three files**:

C:\temp\delete\section1.xml

```
<message>
   <body>
      <tst:commandOption xmlns:tst="http://www.someschema.com/v1.4"
                         xmlns:pc="http://www.someotherschema.com/v1.5"
                         tst:deviceId="1"
                         tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:46"
                         tst:commandId="1"
                         tst:sessionType="response"
                         tst:sessionId="28">
         <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="12" tst:configurationId="3148"/>
      </tst:commandOption>
   </body>
</message>
```

C:\temp\delete\section2.xml

```
<message>
   <body>
      <tst:commandOption xmlns:tst="http://www.someschema.com/v1.4"
                         xmlns:pc="http://www.someotherschema.com/v1.5"
                         tst:deviceId="1"
                         tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:48"
                         tst:commandId="2"
                         tst:sessionType="response"
                         tst:sessionId="29">
         <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="13" tst:configurationId="3149"/>
      </tst:commandOption>
   </body>
</message>
```

C:\temp\delete\section3.xml

```
<message>
   <body>
      <tst:commandOption xmlns:tst="http://www.someschema.com/v1.4"
                         xmlns:pc="http://www.someotherschema.com/v1.5"
                         tst:deviceId="1"
                         tst:dateTime="2012-07-11T15:30:50"
                         tst:commandId="3"
                         tst:sessionType="response"
                         tst:sessionId="30">
         <tst:commandOptionAck tst:transactionId="14"/>
      </tst:commandOption>
   </body>
</message>
```

Comment: Dimitre - Message and body are not simple but contain message ids and date time attribues, etc that need to be copied also. This solution only works for this simple case.

Comment: Dimitre - I attached an actual sample of the message. If you get a simpler solution than the one Dabbler proposed I'm all ears. Thanks!

Comment: @BillCunningham, I would also need the exact wanted result for the provided XML document. Please.

Comment: @BillCunningham, See the updated answer. Although I had to guess what the actual wanted result could be, the same (essentially) transformation handles correctly your "more complicated" XML document.